# In SCSS, how to refer the value in outer scope/block?

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass, media-queries

Following is the snippet in SCSS:

```
.element-a {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 216px;
  height: 232px;
  @media (max-width: 1000px) {
    right: 0;      // Half of 0
    width: 118px;  // Half of 216 px
    height: 116px; // Half of 232 px
  }
}

.element-b {
  position: absolute;
  width: 140px;
  height: 152px;
  right: 216px + 10px;
  @media (max-width: 1000px) {
    width: 70px; // Half of 140px
    height: 76px; // Half of 152px
    right: 113px; // Half of 226px
  }
}
```

As can be seen, if the media-query `max-width:1000px` is satisfied. The attributes `right`, `width` and `height` should be half of its original values.  However, it looks not good practice to hardcode the value by calculating it manually..

Is there a better way to write this in SASS/SCSS? Or is there a way to refer the value in outer scope?

Comment: Why is the Less tag added here?

Comment: @TamilSelvan Thanks. But I thought the percentage in `calc()` is relative to the container size, not relative to the original size..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `variables`, here's an example:

```
$b-width: 140px;

.element-b {
    width: $b-width;
    @media (max-width: 1000px) {
        width: $b-width/2 // Half of $b-width
    }
}
```